# Fail to configure SharePoint 2013 with sql server 2008 sp1 r2

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, installation

I have installed sql server 2008 r2 sp1 and share-point 2013. then i type the following inside the SharePoint 2013 management shell to configure SharePoint to use sql server :-

```
**cmdlet New-SPConfigurationDatabase at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:

DatabaseName: SharePointDev
DatabaseServer: SharePoint_Config
FarmCredentials
Passphrase: *******************

New-SPConfigurationDatabase : Cannot connect to database master at SQL server
at SharePoint_Config. The database might not exist, or the current user does
not have permission to connect to it.
At line:1 char:1

+ New-SPConfigurationDatabase
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...urationDatabase:
   SPCmdletNewSPConfigurationDatabase) [New-SPConfigurationDatabase], SPExcep
  tion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletNewSPCon
   figurationDatabase.**
```

So what might be causing this issue. although i have successfully login to the sql server management studio using the username and password i provided inside the sp2013 management shell.?

and when i tried to configure the DB using the configuration wizard i got the following error :-
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue and has various resolutions.

More often than not it is a firewall issue on the SQL server so check that OR it's that SQL server has not been enabled for remote connections.

I would recommend you follow all the steps and options in this [TechNet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/485bd8ba-9311-4fa6-a038-f7916a49a4bd/cannot-connect-to-database-master-at-sql-server-at-servername) thread and [this blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx).

Hope this helps!

Comment: seems the sql browser service was not started